# How to insert a PushButton widget in arow without replacing the row content in qt

Tags: qt

I have created a table using `QTableWidget`. I want to insert a `QPushButton` widget in a row when the row is getting selected and want to remove the same when the row is getting unselected.

When I tried with `setCellWidget` , i found the widget is replacing my whole row content, which i dont want. So is there any other way in `QTableWidget` for this

or

If i will go for QTableView, there I am thinking of two ways:

1. using delegate
2. setIndexWidget()

Using delegate if I am inserting pushButton widget, then can i perform any operation using signal and slot ??

So i want ask which one i should use for a table, and how to insert a pushButton widget in a row to perform some action ??

Please help me out

Thanks ...

Comment: Yes, if you insert pushButton widget you can perform any operations on it, like with any other widget.

Comment: "without replacing row content"? How it should look like?

Comment: how exactly does it replace whole row? Can you post some screenshot?
you set it like this, right?: `yourTable.setCellWidget(col, row, yourButton)`

Comment: Thanks for your advice.. I tried with setCellWidget, and it worked as i want.